# Node.js changes in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have a question regarding about node.js for mysql.

I'm trying to check for changes in the database with node.js and every time it does a change it would do something.

I have the following code:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'socialpodd',
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM personal', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('Rows: ', rows[0].email);
});

connection.end();
```

But I want this code to be called once there is a change in the database. I know I could do a poll method, but it doesn't seem that effective and real-time. What would be a good real-time module that would allow me to do it, or is polling my only option?